# LocalStorage not working on iPhone - Not in Private Browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, html

I am trying to Save user input from a textarea in localstorage on the unload of a page and then read it back into a textarea when the user returns. It is working fine in a desktop browser, but doesn't seem to be working on my iPhone. This is not the same as the Private Browsing issues that have been previously answered.

Here is the html:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Cookie Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
 </head>
 <body class="full" onload="getText()" onunload="saveText()">
  <div class="fullscreen-overlay" id="fullscreen_overlay">
  <div class="fullscreen-container js-fullscreen-container">
  <div class="textarea-wrap">
  <textarea name="fullscreen-contents" id="fullscreen-contents"></textarea>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript to get and write to localstorage:

```
var text = document.getElementById('fullscreen-contents');

function saveText() {
  localStorage.savedText = text.value;
  console.log("saved");
}

function getText() {
  if (localStorage.savedText) {
    text.value = localStorage.savedText;
    console.log("loaded");
  }
}
```

This is happening in iOS 8 and Private Browsing is not turned on. Any idea what could be going on? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that unload code is not called on iPhones.

Comment: I don't think private browsing allows the use of local storage... https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/issues/42

Comment: I know, but I am referring to regular browsing, not private browsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onpageshow` and `onpagehide` instead of `onload` and `onunload`.

According to the [iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW19) (and same for the [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5)), the `load` and `unload` events are deprecated, and it recommends to use `pageshow` and `pagehide` respectively:

> The `load` and `unload` events may not work as expected for back and forward optimization. Use the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
sessionStorage.setItem('some Key', 'some value');
```

This may not work on some iPhone and iPad OS versions

best solution is to put this code in try and catch so code after this can run

```
 try {
        sessionStorage.setItem('some Key', 'some value');

 }catch(ex) {
    // iOS 8.3+
    /*Does not support session Storage Correctly;
    alert('unsupported'+ex);*/

   }
```